# Como utilizar operador ternário em Flutter/Dart

Tags: mobile, dart

Como fazer o `if/else` em uma linha em *Dart/Flutter*?

Tipo: `variavel ? null : function() : function2()`

Comment: variavel == null ? function() : function2()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

<kbd>Comparação</kbd> `?` <kbd>Valor se verdadeiro</kbd> `:` <kbd>Valor se falso</kbd>`;`

---

Ex.:

```dart
void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var result = i % 2 == 0 ? print("$i - par") : print("$i - impar");
    }
}
```